# Format all labels after a checkbox and radio button with css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have radio buttons and checkboxes with each a label on its right side.

I want to format the label with a margin-left:10px; to have a distant to the radion/check controls.

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]  label {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

This css is moving somehow the whole control + label 10px to the right side...

I just want the left margin on the label.

What do I have to change in my selector?

Comment: use the adjacent operator "+" if the element is next to. As it currently stands, the label tag is nested within the input tag - but that is impossible as the input tag is a single, self enclosing tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`input[type="radio"]  label` is looking for a `label` that's a child of an `input[type=radio]` you want:

```
input[type="radio"] + label
```

for an adjacent sibling label

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify them seperately. In your css you have applied the style to `input[type="checkbox"]` alone also.

Do it like this:

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/aJPaq/

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label, input[type="radio"] +  label {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```